# Pressing enter submits form on login page

Tags: feature-request, login

I have a very simple request that would add lots of value to the trilogy.

When you are in the login screen, the enter key doesn't submit the form.  So, usually, this is what happens to me:

1. click Login
2. start typing my openid site
3. it appears in the dropdown.  I select the full site name.
4. I hit enter.
5. ....
6. ....
7. ....
8. ....
9. ....
10. I come back to the login tab and find that I'm still not logged in.  I then click the login button and curse the fact that enter doesn't submit the form.

Please, change the login screen so that the enter key submits the form.

Comment: What browser are you using??

Comment: Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]
<sub>(source: [typepad.com](https://codinghorror.typepad.com/.a/6a0120a85dcdae970b0128776ff992970c-pi))</sub>

(Firefox, Vista & Linux)

<sub>Image: Jon Galloway, [Source](https://web.archive.org/web/20100120154509/http://www.codinghorror.com:80/blog/archives/000818.html), [License](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)</sub>

Comment: Ditto: [Fx|IE|Chrome|Opera] on Win 7

Comment: Image is gone baby gone. (had to break 15 chars sorry)

Comment: @balpha looks like it's [no longer working](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/224328/152859) in the new login page. Bug, or by design?