# Enter from password field doesn't submit SE login form

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, login, keyboard-shortcuts

On https://security.stackexchange.com/users/login page for a site where I don't yet have an account, if I select the "Log in using Stack Exchange" box, when I hit enter from the password form, nothing happens.

Minor, but...

Comment: Well, [it used to work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19891/152859).

Comment: @ShadowWizard, yeah, I saw that, but it was an awful long time ago...

Comment: True, the login page was redesigned recently so I hope it's a simple overlook on their side.

Answer (score 2):

This will be fixed in the next build.  Hitting enter in the log in or signup forms will submit as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I've added a client-side fix for this issue into the [**Stack Overflow Unofficial Patch**](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch) v1.10.

Basically, the cause of the problem is that the "submit" button on the form is not really a normal `<input type=submit>` element, and so the auto-submit-on-enter feature in most browsers is not applied to the form.  The fix is simply to emulate it with a custom `keypress` event handler in JavaScript, just like is done e.g. for the comment input boxes (which are really `<textarea>`s, and thus also don't auto-submit on enter):

```javascript
var inputs = 'input[name=email], input[name=password]';

$('.login-page #se-login-form').on( 'keypress', inputs, function (e) {
    if ( e.which != 13 || e.shiftKey || e.defaultPrevented ) return;

    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();

    var empty = $(e.delegateTarget).find(inputs).filter('[value=""]');
    if ( empty.length > 0 ) empty.first().focus();
    else $(e.delegateTarget).find('#submit-button').click();
} );
```

What this code does is trigger on <kbd>Enter</kbd> key presses in either of the e-mail / password input boxes, assuming that (just to be safe) no other event handler has stopped them or prevented their default behavior yet.  It then checks if both of the fields are filled, and, if so, simulates a click on the submit button; otherwise, it transfers input focus to the first empty field.

Comment: ...and now that it's fixed, this code has been removed from SOUP v1.12.