# Using ENTER for login

Tags: feature-request, design, user-interface, login

Since yesterday I need to use the mouse to login using the StackExchange service.

The day before, when the services were horizontally on a line, it worked fine.
Today with the services vertically on a column I need to use the mouse to login :(

I tested on Windows/MSIE, Windows/Firefox and BSD/Firefox.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224328/enter-from-password-field-doesnt-submit-se-login-form/224869#224869

Comment: @jonsca: Not just related, looks like an exact duplicate to me.

Comment: Ps. Tabbing *does* work, and so does pressing enter *when the submit button has focus*, so you can use the sequence *email* -> `Tab` -> *password* -> `Tab` -> `Enter` to log in using the keyboard only. Or just install [SOUP](http://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch).

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I hesitated because the other one was a bug report and this is a feature request, but I'm leaning that way.

Comment: @jonsca: The difference between a [meta-tag:bug] and a [meta-tag:feature-request] is kind of fuzzy, anyway. Both are basically statements that "this does not work the way it should"; a feature request just expresses it as a personal opinion, while a bug report claims it as an objective fact.